# 3 Dimensional array in C

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10][20][30]={0};
    printf("%d %d %d",&a+1 - &a, 
       a[10][20] - a[10][10], a[10] - a[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

I know how 2-D array works but I don't understand this piece of code, Please help me to visualize it.
I know if we define a[3][3] then a point to address of whole first array and *a point to address of address first element of first array and value of &a=a=*a will have same value in C but they're different. I understand till this part but I'm not able to visualize 3-d array.

Comment: printf("%d %d %d",&a+1 - &a, 
       a[10][20] - a[10][10], a[10] - a[5]); // Sir In this line we're accessing a[10][20] but in memory array are stored from 0-9 then why it isn't giving an error? Can you share your thoughts on it ?

Comment: For starters, the types are wrong. `%d` is for signed `int`, pointer difference type is `ptrdiff_t` and should be printed as `%td` if your toolchain supports it, otherwise punt and use `%ld` and/or  (shudder) cast. Also, *types* are important. Pointer differencing accounts against the type. The resulting values are therefore based on that. Finally, this code invokes UB. The only valid indexes for the superior dimension of that array are `0..9` inclusive. Similar with the second dimension (`0..19`).

Comment: @RobertAntanio Re the use of e.g. `a[10]` you ask "why it isn't giving an error" - In C there is no "range check" on array access. In other words - if you try to access an array using a "too high" index, the system will not give you an error message like "Error: Out of range access" or similar. It's your responsibility that your program doesn't do such things. All the C standard says about it, is that it is "undefined" what happens in case of out-of-range access. In other words... anything can happen.

Comment: @4386427 there is no ***"out of range access"*** only pointer arithmetic. It is not UB and you are wrong.

Comment: @0___________ Pointer arithmetic using pointers outside the array is UB

Answer (score 0):

`a[x]` - is [20[30] integer array.

`a[x][y]` is a 30 elements array of pointers.

All arrays decay to pointers.

When you  `a[10][20] - a[10][10]` or `&a+1 - &a` you simply do some pointer arithmetic and the result has a type of `ptrdiff_t`. It is an integer type. You should use `%zi` format specifier to print `ptrdiff_t` data. But in this case, it works as the result does not exceed the integer range.

There is no UB in this code as you do not access any elements of the array.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic using pointers outside the array is UB